# GraphQL - Custom Fields

Tags: javascript, graphql, graphql-js

Given the following interface, where `customFields` is just a dictionary dynamically populated by the user...

**how can I represent it on a gql schema?**

```js
interface CustomThing {
  id: string;

  customFields: {
    [key: string]: unknown;
  }
}
```

---

The question is more 
**how can I represent `{ [key: string]: unknown }` in graphql?**

Answer (score 1):

You can define a custom scalar type, often called `JSON`, and make a field of that type on your GraphQL interface. See [this library](https://github.com/taion/graphql-type-json) for an example implementation.